# Name for a spin state with a multiplicity of 13

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, terminology, spin

If I want to name a spin state with 12 unpaired electrons,
what is the correct name?
Tredecim is the latin name for thirteen, but tredecimet sounds odd.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have seen multiplicity 13 referred to as simply a 13-let. This #-let nomenclature is sometimes used for high multiplicities (e.g. higher than 10).

Answer (score -2):

I would go for the Greek form and call it trisdecatet. Or should it be with a k, trisdekatet?

Comment: All other spin states use latin for their name. This would be very inconsistent.